XML root element missing in SCCM
I encountered a problem that caused the SCCM configuration manager console to stop displaying application information due to a XML corruption.
looked around a bit on the internet and found the following explanations:

corrupted .net framework
corrupted admin console client
corrupted odbc drivers

So i tried the following:

Tried reinstalling The configmgr admin console
Tried fixing dotnet
Tried installing a newer version of dotnet
Tried repairing all available ODBC drivers

all to no avail

This problem is caused by a configuration file corruption.
i have found the following solution to this issue:
shut down the console
go to %Localappdata%\Microsoft\Configmgr10
and remove the following file:
"Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.ApplicationManagement.config"
this will cause the console to regenerate the file on the next run.
